# Testing for palindrome using loops going wrong

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, palindrome

What this program is trying to do is go through numbers starting at "000000" going all the way up to "999999" and trying to find numbers which are palindromes. (eg: 0000000000).
I am having trouble with reversing the string and creating a valid result. The system adds the next 4 numbers creating a length 10 string.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class TestPalindrome{

 public static void main(String []args){
    int[] intArray = new int[6];
    String[] strArray = new String[99];
    String nextString;
    int count = 0;
    int nextnum;
    int thisnum;
    String thisString = "";
    String s = "000000";
       nextString = s;   
do {       
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)    {
  intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(nextString.charAt(i)));
                            }
   int pos1 = intArray[5];
   int pos2 = intArray[4]*10;
   int pos3 = intArray[3]*100;
   int pos4 = intArray[2]*1000;
   int pos5 = intArray[1]*10000;
   int pos6 = intArray[0]*100000;
   nextnum = (pos1 + 1) + pos2 + pos3 + pos4 + pos5 + pos6;
   thisnum = pos1 + pos2 + pos3 + pos4 + pos5 + pos6;


// If any of below values = 10, then number is not used
int d7 = ((4*intArray[0])+(10*intArray[1])+(9*intArray[2])+(2*intArray[3])+intArray[4]+(7*intArray[5])) % 11;
int d8 = ((7*intArray[0])+(8*intArray[1])+(7*intArray[2])+(intArray[3])+9*intArray[4]+(6*intArray[5])) % 11;
int d9 = ((9*intArray[0])+(intArray[1])+(7*intArray[2])+(8*intArray[3])+7*intArray[4]+(7*intArray[5])) % 11;
int d10 = ((intArray[0])+(2*intArray[1])+(9*intArray[2])+(10*intArray[3])+4*intArray[4]+(intArray[5])) % 11;


if (d7==10) {  }
else if (d8==10) { }
else if (d9==10) {  }
else if (d10==10) { }
else {

String s7 = Integer.toString(d7);
String s8 = Integer.toString(d8);
String s9 = Integer.toString(d9);
String s10 = Integer.toString(d10);
 thisString = String.format("%06d", thisnum);
String concat = thisString + s7 + s8 + s9 + s10;

StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder(concat);   
StringBuilder value = input.reverse();
if( value == input){
        System.out.println("" + concat);
        strArray[count] = concat;
        count = count+1; 
}
else {}


}
         nextString = String.format("%06d", nextnum);
    }
         while (nextnum < 1000000 && nextnum > 000000);{

          }
 }
}
```

The problem is that it displays all numbers and not just palindromes. Any help is very welcomed.

Comment: Your code looks quite complex... Maybe I didn't get what you wanna do, but why don't you just check for each number if the digit at position i is the same as the one at n-i, where n is the total number of digits.

Comment: I agree with @EdgarBoda, this is a lot of code. Definitely try to simplify your algorithm.  Even if you get what you have to work, chances are you won't understand this if you look at it in a few weeks.

Comment: I think the problem stems from the fact that it isn't storing variable thisnum as 000001 and is storing it as just 1.

Comment: You can use `String.format("%06d", x);` to get a String representation of legnth 6 for `x` with padded zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply put the numbers into strings. Then reverse the string and see if it equals the original.

```
String originalString = "110011";
String newString = new StringBuilder(originalString ).reverse().toString();
if (originalString.equals(newString )) {
    //Is a palindrome
}
```

**Note**: Consider how you want to handle leading zeros. "11" is a palindrome, but if you need 4 values then "0011" is not.

Comment: This makes sense, I thought that this line would handle the leading 0's:
thisString = String.format("%06d", thisnum);

Comment: That line should. If `thisnum` was equal to `15` then it should be `000015`.

Answer (score 0):

One funny way is to use just one for-loop :

```
public static void main(String [] args){

        for(String s = "000000"; !s.equals("1000000");  s = String.format("%06d",Integer.parseInt(s)+1)){
            if(new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString().equals(s))
                System.out.println(s);
        }
}
```